# Question about conventions for notation of random and regular variables in this regression example

Tags: regression, random-variable, notation

I’m trying to follow some lectures notes on regression I found online and want to make sure I’m interpreting the notations correctly.

On page 4 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/01/lecture-01.pdf), we have $\mu(x) = E[Y | X = x]$. Is it correct to call $x$ a regular variable that has no probability distribution and $\mu(x)$ computes the expected value of $Y$ when $X$ is fixed to $x$? Something like $E[Y|X]$ would instead be a random variable (with the probability distribution of $X$) and thus is a function $X$ (upper case)?

At the bottom of page 12 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/03/lecture-03.pdf), we have $Y|X = \beta_0 + \beta_1x+\epsilon$, I’m assuming that lower case $x$ is used as the equation is trying to say, if $X = x$, then $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x+\epsilon$?

On page 1 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/04/lecture-04.pdf) where $Y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\epsilon_i$, the capital $X_i$ indicate that we are not only looking at a specific value of $X$? The author uses both $(X_1, Y_1),\dots,(X_n, Y_n)$ and $(x_1, y_1),\dots,(x_n, y_n)$ (in the middle of page 2) to describe $n$ data points. Does capitalization in the former imply a sample whose value hasn't been determined while latter indicates actual data?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular variable"? A symbol representing a number? The page 12 notation is  a typographical error: both sides should agree on their use of "$X$" or "$x$;" the subsequent material (see the top of p. 13) makes it clear "$X$" was intended. The bottom of p. 12 indicates it could refer to a random variable or a number: "The distribution of $X$ is unspecified, possibly even deterministic." The page 1 notation is explained at the outset: "$X_i$" may have a distribution "and perhaps $X$ is even non-random." In other words, pick your interpretation in that passage: both are valid.

Comment: In brief: *ignore conventions.*  Read the text carefully and learn whatever convention it uses.  Use context to sort out ambiguous passages (such as those with typographical errors).